# "Schönen Dank" als eine Antwort auf "Guten Tag"?

Tags: word-choice

Aus Grimms Märchen "Rotkäppchen":

> "Guten Tag, Rotkäppchen!" sprach [der Wolf]. "Schönen Dank, Wolf!"

Wenn man "Good day" in English sagt, würde niemand mit "thank you" antworten. Es wäre unhöflich.

Ist das häufig in Deutsch gesagt? Oder ist es nur in diesem Märchen?

Answer (score 3):

*"Schönen Dank"* wurde heute weitgehend durch *"Danke schön"* ersetzt. Damit gibt man dem einfachen *"Danke"* noch eine besondere, intensivierende Note.

Es wird sehr häufig benutzt, auch in dem genannten Kontext. So kann man sich durchaus für den Wunsch nach einem *schönen* oder *guten* Tag bedanken:

> Eine schönen Tag wünsche ich dir! - *Oh, Danke schön, dir auch!*
>   Ihnen noch einen guten Tag. - *Danke, Ihnen auch.*

Das ist anders bei der Großformel "Guten Tag". Hier ist es auch bei uns heute üblich, die Grußformel einfach zu wiederholen:

> Guten Tag, Mirov. - *Guten Tag, Takkat.*

Das heißt aber nicht, dass eine andere Formulierung falsch oder gar unhöflich wäre. So ist

> Guten Tag, Takkat. - *Danke, Mirov.*

durchaus möglich, wenn auch kaum gebräuchlich, da sie den formelhaft verwendeten Wunsch wörtlich zu nehmen scheint.

Answer (score 2):

Ich halte es für unwahrscheinlich, für mich üblich ist "Danke, Ihnen auch/ebenfalls". Letzten Endes enthalten Grimms Märchen an vielen Stellen doch recht veraltetes, aber schönes Deutsch.

Answer (score 1):

Im normalen Leben antwortet man ebenfalls mit "Guten Tag". "Schönen Dank" habe ich als Antwort noch nie gehört, würde mir auch sehr komisch vorkommen.